# Android won't show special character from PHP page

Tags: java, php, android

I have a simple web page that displays the word "Entrée". It looks perfect on the web but, when I use an HTTPClient in Android to show the webpage that should display this single word it does not know how to handle the "é". I'm not familiar with character codes and such, but I've been looking around and have seen that most people recommend UTF-8. How do I make sure Android can read this special character?

Webpage PHP code:

`<?php echo "Entrée"; ?>`

Any ideas?

Comment: This has something to do with Android, not php.

Comment: @The Man It might, depending on the character encoding (not) set by the PHP script.

Comment: Maybe there is something in the php code I can use to replace the "é" so that it will display fine in Android and on the webpage.

Comment: You can avoid most character encoding trouble by escaping any special (mostly non-ASCII) characters as [HTML entites](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp). é would be `&eacute;` for example. The best solution is of course to make your PHP script set the right character encoding headers, be itself encoded correctly and properly use UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: To do that programmatically I would search the text first and replace any "é" with "&eacute;" in a simple if statement?

Comment: @PhilippReichart I think you should describe that in an answer, since it seems like a very plausible solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @Hassan Yep, that's what I've been doing for the past 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a character encoding issue. The PHP script probably doesn't set any/the correct character encoding header, so your browser and Android assume whatever they like.

*Please dont do this, it's dirty:* <strike>A **quick hack** to avoid most character encoding trouble is escaping any special (mostly non-ASCII) characters as [HTML entites](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp). é would be `&eacute;` for example. If you only ever want to `echo "Entrée"`, then just find-and-replace in your favorite text editor.</strike>

*Do this instead, it makes the world a better place:*

If you plan to output anything more than a static word, say some dynamic text from a database or so, you should really try to **do the right thing**: Make your PHP script output UTF-8 and sent the correct `Content-Type` header along.

My PHP is very rusty, but something like  this should work:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
echo "Entrée";
?>
```

You also need to *make sure* your text editor or IDE **saves your PHP file as UTF-8** (not ANSI, ASCII, Windows-1252 or some such) or the `é` will be all messed up and no header-setting will fix it. Most editors will happenly save in ANSI which might look fine in your editor, but blow up in your face when viewed in a browser.

Comment: That code gave me an output of "Entr�e" on the webpage. Will try some tweaking. EDIT: It also gave an output of "Entr�e" in the Android application as well.

Comment: Did you save our PHP file as UTF-8? You might also want to check with Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug if your PHP script is sending the correct `Content-Type` header.

Comment: I just tried out the above PHP snippet and I ran into Notepad trying to save it as ANSI... You really have to force it as UTF-8 and then it works :) Oh, and prefer something like SFTP/SCP (instead of FTP) that doesn't tend to mess with what it considers text files to upload your files to the server if the time comes.

Comment: Hmm... I'm just trying that exact code snippet saved as an index.php and it's still giving me the "Entr�e". Any ideas?

Comment: Copying it out of the browser window and pasting it into your editor does no harm. Saving does most likely break it, check if your editor allows to "Save As..." where you can force UTF-8 as file encoding.

Comment: Saving in Notepad++ does not mention anything about file encoding when in the save as box. Hrm... =/

Comment: Just downloaded Notepad++, there's an menu labelled "Encoding". Change it to UTF-8 without BOM (BOMs usually only break stuff) and *then* paste the Entrée string into it. If you do it before setting the Encoding, it will just produce garbage as before.

Comment: Hachaa... That did it. Thanks so much. Wouldn't have been possible without ya. Thanks again!